# Execute Excel VBA Macro using SAS

Tags: vba, excel, sas

I have SAS EG version 7.1 and Office 2013 Installed on my system. I am trying to run my SAS projects by calling them from VBA. As a first step, I tried to call a simple PROC step using the below code I found online:

```
Sub createTable()
    Dim obObjectFactory As New SASObjectManager.ObjectFactory

    Dim obObjectKeeper As New SASObjectManager.ObjectKeeper

    Dim obServer As New SASObjectManager.ServerDef

    Dim obSAS as SAS.workspace

    Dim query as String
    query = "PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE ME.TABLE1; RUN;"

    obServer.MachineDNSName = "XXXXXXXXX"
    obServer.Protocol = ProtocolBridge
    obServer.Port = 8561
    obObjectFactory.LogEnabled = True

    Set obSAS = obObjectFactory.CreateObjectByServer("SASApp", True, obServer, "", "")

    obSAS.LanguageService.Submit query

End Sub
```

But I'm getting the Runtime error '-2147213310 at below line:

```
Set obSAS = obObjectFactory.CreateObjectByServer("SASApp", True, obServer, "", "")
```

[Runtime error '-2147213310](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMXev.jpg)
Can anyone please help me to move forward this error? Also, any guidance to run the SAS projects is greatly appreciated. I am new to both VBA and SAS.

Answer (score 1):

Error says you are connecting to the metadata server and not the workspaceserver.

According to [this](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Calling-SAS-through-VBA/td-p/79673?nobounce):

1) The workspaceservers default port is 8591.

2) The workspaceserver may also run on a different machine. Connect to your profile, go to the serverlist, locate the server you want to connect to and right click the context menu "properties" to see the right connection profile for your workspaceserver.

Suggested connection details:

obServer.MachineDNSName = "XXXXXXX"

obServer.Protocol = SASObjectManager.Protocols.ProtocolBridge

obServer.Port = 8591

Set obSAS = obObjectFactory.CreateObjectByServer("sas", True, obServer, Nothing, Nothing)

Unsure whether difference between using `SASApp` v `sas` so suggest you try with the first and if that fails then try with the second.

Comment: I had similar issue.. Couldn't find any solution. Changing the port didn't work. And changing the Set statement with "Nothing" as variable as well causes Automation Error

Comment: I agree.. Tried the solution you gave @QHarr but it's not working. Throwing "Automation Error" with same error number

Comment: I’ll give it another go later or tomorrow